# Launch animations only once

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a powerpoint presentation (pwpt 2021) where several animations are displayed while diaporama mode is activated with `F5`.

At the end of the presentation, we usually go through each slide on diaporama mode (`F5` still activated).

The issue is that each animation, for example `appear`, has to animate everytime we go through each slide (it `appears` when you go forward and `disapears` when you go backward). Optimally it would only `appear` once and stay still.

Is there a way to only activate animations once during a presentation so that we can go back to each slide without disturbing the diaporama lecture? (with or without encoding)

Here is an example of what currently happens:

[image]

And this is what I would love to see when I go back to the previous slides during the presentation:

[image]

Overall it would be like that during a presentation:

[image]

**Macro attempt**

As a novice in VBA, I took my inspiration from the following topic (based on Bradipo comment):
https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/vba/powerpoint-vba-remove-all-animation-effects

So I created 3 slides with an animation on the second slide.
I incorporated the following code in a macro:

```
Sub RemoveAllAnimations()
'PURPOSE: Remove All PowerPoint Animations From Slides
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault

Dim sld As Slide
Dim x As Long
Dim Counter As Long

'Loop Through Each Slide in ActivePresentation
    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides

'Loop through each animation on slide
        For x = sld.TimeLine.MainSequence.Count To 1 Step -1

'Remove Each Animation
            sld.TimeLine.MainSequence.Item(x).Delete

'Maintain Deletion Stat
            Counter = Counter + 1

        Next x

    Next sld

'Completion Notification
MsgBox Counter & " Animation(s) were removed from you PowerPoint presentation!"

End Sub
```

When I executed the code, I had the message: "1 Animation(s) were removed from you PowerPoint presentation!".

This is nice but it killed the animations when diaporama mode was not activated with `F5`, it just killed them all instead of removing them during the presentation.

**Macro + button attempt**

As suggested by Bradipo, I created a button in the very last slide and connected it to the macro.

- Insert shape at the very last slide
- Select object then: Insert -> Action -> Execute macro -> Select macro of interest
- Launch presentation in `F5` mode an click on the button at the end (great, it works!)

The only remaining issue is that it kills the animations instead of just removing them during the presentation, meaning that I would have to re-create each animation afterward.

Comment: From the error it seems there is only one shape in the slide, not two. have you tried with `With ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange`?

Comment: Thank you @Bradipo, I updated and it seems that there is a function that does no more exist, it says it says that the following object does not exist ` effNew.Delete`. Do you know what is the reason for this? Thanks

Comment: I am looking into this, but I have little experience with animations in VBA. I have found this, https://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ00071_Animations-_Sounds-_Movies_play_only_once.htm | I actually think the best would be to run a macro that deletes all animations once the presentation has bee shown, wouldn't it be easier? https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/vba/powerpoint-vba-remove-all-animation-effects

Comment: Thank you for the link, I also believe it is a good idea to delete animations once the presentation is over. I tried the code, updated the indentation and no error message was found, I then tried to launch my powerpoint (similar to the example I showed) but the animations remained. What was surprising on the other hand is that I received a message when I executed the macro: `"2 Animation(s) were removed from you PowerPoint presentation!"` and it removed my animations but not while I was under Presentation mode (F5 activated).

Comment: Maybe you could try to put the macro in a button in the last slide of the presentation, so it should be accessible from the presentation mode. But I am only guessing here...

Comment: I tested it and it worked in both ways, however sometimes the animation was still playing. I would say that the button at the end of the presentation is more comfortable though.

Comment: Perfect, I created a button and associated the macro to it. When I run my powerpoint, all the animations run once, then I click on button (message is displayed). And I can come back to previous slides without the issue. The only remaining problem is that it kills all animations instead of removing it them only for the presentation, which means I cannot run twice the presentation. Any idea on this? Also, if you want to write your current comments into an answer, I would be pleased to mark it as `Solution`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you last comment I understand that you would rather *disable* the animations, than delete them. I would then suggest you simply do not save the file after the animations are removed - thus keeping the above code I linked you from TheSpreadsheetGuru -, so the actions made by the Macro are only temporary. You may also *Undo* any action right after the removal, luckily PowerPoint does not act like Excel after a macro has done something.

Else, I made the below to toggle between animations on and off, however this works only with the presentation is in editing mode (that is, you have to exit presentation mode). Unfortunately it cannot be added to a button to use during the presentation. It is the same as clicking on *Set Up Slide Show* (below screenshots) and tick/untick the box. Such option, as well as the whole *Set Up* group, are all greyed out in Presentation Mode, and likely VBA cannot access such menu either unless while editing.

```
Sub ToggleAnimation()


If ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.ShowWithAnimation = msoFalse Then

    ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.ShowWithAnimation = msoTrue

    MsgBox "Animations are ON"


ElseIf ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.ShowWithAnimation = msoTrue Then

    ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.ShowWithAnimation = msoFalse

    MsgBox "Animations are OFF"

End If

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]